# How to programatically install Google Workspace add-on app which is deployed using gcp cloud run

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-cloud-run, google-apps-marketplace

I have created a Google Workspace Add app, which I created and deployed with cloud run.
Now I have to deploy the app to selected users in an organization after getting admin credentials using Admin Google API.

Comment: What is the issue here? Can you elaborate the question with more details?

Comment: So the issue is we have a billing platform where the admin onboards users all its users and we need make the app available for all users selected by admin see the add on application. Without navigating to Google admin console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is no way to install Addons programatically - be it through [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/apis) or [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk), however you can do it centrally from the [Admin Console](https://admin.google.com/)

For this

- follow the instructions for [Automatically install apps and extensions](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6306504?hl=en)
- Go on https://admin.google.com/ac/chrome/apps/user
- Select an organisatiomal unit where you want to apply the `Force install` (you might need to create this unit first and move to it all the selected users)
- Click on the yellow "plus" at the bottom right and select "Add by URL"

[image]

- Type in the Marketplace Listing of your Addon and click `Save`
- Adjust `Additonal Settings` if necessary

[image]